# A priority queue supporting LIFO push and pop?

Tags: data-structures, stack, priority-queue

I need to design a "priority queue stack" data structure with the following constraints:

- pop() and deleteMin() run in O(log(n)) in the average case.
- push(x) and getMin() run in O(1) in the average time

Does anyone have suggestions about how to design this?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this by combining together a standard stack with a priority queue that supports O(1) insertion and O(log n) amortized deletion.  For example, you could pair the stack with a Fibonacci heap or skew binomial heap, both of which have these guarantees.  Make sure to store pointers lining each stack element with its corresponding priority queue element so that in O(1) time you can jump between the two.

To push an element, push it on the stack and insert it to the priority queue in O(1) time.  To read off the minimum, query the priority queue for the minimum value in O(1) time.

To delete the minimum, call extract-min from the priority queue to remove the minimum value, then go to the stack and mark the removed element as invalid.  This takes O(1) time.  To pop, repeatedly pop the stack until you pop an element that is not marked invalid, then call delete on the priority queue to remove that element.  This takes time O(k + log n), where k is the number of pops performed.  However, you can show that this is amortized O(1) by using the potential method.  If you set the potential of the stack to be the number of invalid arguments, each delete-min increases the potential by one, and each pop operation that pops k invalid elements decreases the potential by k.  Therefore, the amortized runtime of a pop is O(log n).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack with point to Minimum Value Object. So in that case push(x),pop(), getMin() will be in O(1) - in the average time.

But after deleteMin(), you need to adjust the top items.

Comment: How would you do deleteMin() on O(log n) ? with a normal stack it seems difficult :p

Comment: Please do not implement the Stack as Array, rather implement it as Double LinkList. Always have 3 pointer ( Header, Min Item pointer, Last Item Pointer.     
push --> Add item at end of Double LinkList.
pop --> remove the item at end of LinkList.

In this case all operation pop(), push(x), getMin() will have O(1).
Only deleteMin, will not have O(1) average time, because you need to   recalculate the next Min; but you can always optimize it by having "2 Min" pointer. At time of push, we need to check the pushed value to Min pointer value and change Min pointer it needed.